# multiple serverless process on different ports

Tags: serverless

I am having multiple serverless applications I am running it locally using serverless offline plugin

I am setting ports like

```
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 4000
```

another serverless

```
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 3000
```

At any time I am able to run only one service other shows :

> Unexpected error while starting serverless-offline lambda server on
> port 3002: { Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use

But I am not using 3002 anywhere but it shows 3002

what is this error?

> 127.0.0.1:3002

Answer (score 26):

## Update November 2023

If you go to the serverless docs, you can see that there are four different ports that serverless uses:

```
$ sls offline --help | grep " port "
--albPort                       ALB port to listen on. Default: 3003.
--httpPort                      HTTP port to listen on. Default: 3000.
--lambdaPort                    Lambda http port to listen on. Default: 3002.
--websocketPort                 Websocket port to listen on. Default: 3001.
```

You have to specify all 4 of them if you want to run multiple serverless offline lambda servers. The first serverless config should thus look like:

```yaml
custom:
    serverless-offline:
        httpPort: 4000
        websocketPort: 4001
        lambdaPort: 4002
        albPort: 4003
```

Thanks to sidonai for pointing this out in the comments!

## Old answer

If you go to the serverless docs, you can see that there are three different ports that serverless uses:

```bash
$ sls offline --help | grep " port "$
--httpPort ......................... HTTP port to listen on. Default: 3000
--lambdaPort ....................... Lambda http port to listen on. Default: 3002
--websocketPort .................... Websocket port to listen on. Default: 3001
```

You have to specify all 3 of them if you want to run multiple serverless offline lambda servers. The first serverless config should thus look like:

```yaml
custom:
    serverless-offline:
        httpPort: 4000
        websocketPort: 4001
        lambdaPort: 4002
```

Comment: with latest releases, now there are four different ports, defaults are

    serverless-offline:
        httpPort: 3000
        websocketPort: 3001
        lambdaPort: 3002
        albPort: 3003